# Linux virtualization on Windows (KVM like)

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, qemu, intel-haxm

I know it's possible to virtualize Windows on Linux using KVM and QEMU and get near native performances.
The thing is I have a PC running Windows 10 and everything is setup perfectly so having to install Linux and re-setup my Windows wouldn't be the most optimal solution for me.

So I'm wondering if there is an actual way to do the opposite: **Windows as host, a Linux distro as guest**.

I guess this could be the best for me as I play video games on this computer and still want to have native performances. I heard about intel's HAXM but don't know if this is a good lead as people seem to mostly use it for Android virtualization.

Thank you :)

Comment: It's called Microsoft Hyper-V

Comment: Hyper-V is only available on Pro & Enterprise editions, providing the same performance as if the VM was the main OS, able to specify the amount of RAM and CPU cores, among others, which can be dynamically allocated. Hyper-V is generally superior to most other platforms as it's a Type 1 hypervisor, whereas VirtualBox, QEMU, VMware Workstation, and others are a Type 2 ([reference](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/what-is-hypervisor-type-1-2)). Other options are to dual-boot Linux or use WSL, however I'm partial to Hyper-V due to seamless integration via RDP, such as copy/paste between host & client.

Comment: Ok, I'll check Hyper-V. Thank you

Comment: I found this wikipedia article "[Comparison of platform virtualization software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software)" if anyone's interested.

Comment: You may also P2V existing Windows and run it as VM in KVM. Check - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter